# Trying to add all my specified registry files to the reigstry within a batch file

Tags: batch-file

As the questions says I am trying to call all my specified registry files (.reg) files with a simple batch file. When the user clicks on the batch file it will run and add .reg files to the registry, i also need this to run silently without a Administrative Privileges popup to make changes to the registry. So for example say Quicktime.Mov is the registry file i would like to call and add to the registry, when Quicktime.Mov.reg is called from mybatch.bat it runs a script and adds that specified .reg file to registry without the user knowing, I am not trying to make anything malicious its actually quite the opposite, I am trying to correct some errors people are having when installing quicktime. If your confused and i didn't explain this well then i will try my utter most best to help define it more without having a long run on sentence. Thanks again by helping me with this you will be helping others fix quicktime's installation error.

Comment: This sounds like a really, really Bad Idea.  IMHO...

Comment: I know it sounds like a bad idea but to clarify something if your thinking I want a batch file to add it self to the registry so every time the user turns on the computer it automatically starts up and runs again then your sorely mistaken. I don't need it to add it self to automatically run, i just need to call the registry files all in one simple batch file to add all registry files to regedit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `.reg` files to the registry silently with batch using this:

`regedit.exe /s regfile.reg`

If it requires admin rights to add to the registry i.e. in `HKLM` then it might error or just not work, but I think that's the best you can do with batch.